# C#: How to change the back- or fore color of a row

Tags: c#, listview, colors, styles

i have the following Code for my ListView:
The Code works very fine and i get all the Items in my ListView.

My Problem is that i dont know where i must set the Color of a Row.

```
private DataTable dt;
private DataView dv;
private List<Player> players;

public Form1()
{
   InitializeComponent();
   
   listView1.View = View.Details;
   listView1.AutoResizeColumns(ColumnHeaderAutoResizeStyle.HeaderSize);
   
   listView1.Columns.Add("Name", 150);
   listView1.Columns.Add("Team", 150);

   dt = new DataTable();
   dt.Columns.Add("Name");
   dt.Columns.Add("Team");


   // HERE I CALL THE FUNCTIONS TO FILL THE DATATABLE
   fillDataTable(generateData());
   populateListView(dv);

}

private List<Player> generateData()
{
   players = new List<Player>()
   {
      new Player("Max", "Team Blue"),
      new Player("John", "Team Yellow"),
      new Player("Simon", "Team Yellow"),
      new Player("Tera", "Team Blue")
   };

   return players;
}

private void fillDataTable(List<Player> players)
{
   foreach(var player in players)
   {
      dt.Rows.Add(player.Name, player.Team);
   }
}

private populateListView(DataView dv)
{
   listView1.Items.Clear();
   foreach(DataRow row in dv.ToTable().Rows)
   {
      listView1.Items.Add(new ListViewItem(new String[] {row[0].ToString(), row[1].ToString()}));
   }
}

class Player
{
   private string name;
   private string team;

   public Player( string name, string team)
   {
      this.name = name;
      this.team = team;
   }
   
   public string Name {get { return name;}}
   public string Team {get { return name;}}
}
```

My Problem is that i dont know how to set the Back- or Forecolor.
Any Idea how i can set the Color of a row dynamically?

Comment: See the [ListViewItem Constructors](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.listviewitem.-ctor?view=netcore-3.1). There are constructors include the back/fore colors among other properties. Or create the `ListViewItem` first, set the required properties, then add it to the `ListView.Items` collection. Also when you loop to add items through the `Add` method, you should call the `ListView.BeginUpdate();` method before clearing the current items and the `ListView.EndUpdate();`  after the loop.

Comment: If i set in the "populateListView" metho the color all Items get the same Color. I want to set only the color of one row